# Angular SlicePipe with negative values

Tags: angular

The slice pipe is not including the last digit in the array for Angular.

I am working on the project, and need slice pipe in Angular.

The following is the code for the same:

```
<p>{{ [1,2,3,4,5,6] | slice:0:-1 }}</p>
```

In this case the output is `1,2,3,4,5`

I know with Angular slice pipe no with second parameter is excluded.

There is no error and, I am expecting value of `1,2,3,4,5,6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular [`SlicePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) behavior is based on the expected behavior of the JavaScript API `Array.prototype.slice()` and `String.prototype.slice()`. The `end` parameter of `slice` extracts ***up to but not including end***.

### JavaScript Example

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
a.slice(0, -1);
```

#### Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

## Angular Docs for `SlicePipe`

> Creates a new Array or String containing a subset (slice) of the elements.
>
> ### Usage notes
>
> All behavior is based on the expected behavior of the JavaScript API `Array.prototype.slice()` and `String.prototype.slice()`.
>
> When operating on an `Array`, the returned `Array` is always a copy even when all the elements are being returned.
>
> When operating on a blank value, the pipe returns the blank value.

## [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) Documentation

> ***arr*.slice([*begin*[, *end*]])**
>
> ***begin*** - Zero-based index at which to begin extraction.
>
> ***end*** - Zero-based index before which to end extraction. `slice` extracts ***up to but not including end***.

Comment: but i want to include last value in array with negative as well

Comment: @Avdhut The `end` value may be excluded to get the entire array, for example, `{{ [1,2,3,4,5,6] | slice:0 }}`, but then there is no need to use `slice` at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I know with Angular slice pipe no with second parameter is excluded.

That statement of yours is incorrect. Angular has a second parameter for `SlicePipe`. The first parameter is the `start` and the second (optional) parameter is the `end`. (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)). Here is what the `SlicePipe` accepts

```html
{{ value_expression | slice : start [ : end ] }}
```

All behavior is based on the expected behavior of the JavaScript API Array.prototype.slice() and String.prototype.slice().

You can see exactly what will happen when you change the `start`/`end` values in the pipe [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Syntax).

If you want to include the last value as well, just don't include an `end` value

```js
<p>{{ [1,2,3,4,5,6] | slice: 0 }}</p>
```

If you do not pass a `start` value, `slice` begins with `0`. With this in mind, we can rewrite the above code

```js
<p>{{ [1,2,3,4,5,6] | slice }}</p>
```